# WebM in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, video, proprietary

When I try to play a webm file in Ubuntu touch, it tells me the file is unsupported. Sometimes it'll play properly, sometimes just audio, and sometimes not at all.

Why does Ubuntu Touch support the proprietary codec H.264, but not the open-source codec VP8/VP9? Even stranger, YouTube plays VP9 just fine in the browser.

Is there a way to play WebM on Ubuntu Touch yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you Ubuntu touch device doesn't have support for hardware decoding of WebM where as most phones and tablets e.g. the M10 will have hardware which decodes H.264 so it doesn't take up time on the main CPU while playing H.264 videos.

I'm sure you can install something to play WebM especially if you get the phone/tablet into read/write mode, that said I doubt it would perform very well.

Comment: Pretty much every device doesn't have hardware decoding for WebM, yet Ubuntu Desktop can still play it. And the browser can handle WebM content from YouTube just fine.